# Rich Text value display in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I pulled the Bold text value  from tinymce editor as a json format and I got the below output

```
label: "__Sample Ipsum__"
```

While trying to display the value in the webpage it displays like `__Sample Ipsum__`  and not as `<b> Sample Ipsum </B>` . I tried many references from google nothing worked.

Can you please give me  the solution to display without underscore  **Sample Ipsum**  with  tag using react , JS or HTML.

Comment: Can't you get the content of tinymce in HTML format?? Like `label: "<b>Sample Ipsum</b>" `?? If yes it's solved using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: No I am not getting with "<b>"  tag. I am getting with "__". Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Do you have access to tinymce code ? as described in documentation you can get the content in HTML Format using `.getContent()` method

Comment: I have only json format value and not access to tinymce code.

Comment: It's very strange that the editor returns underscores instead of html tags.

Comment: Is there anyway i can convert using JS